# The Target URI doesn't Exist:'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

Importing Dependencies in **Pubsec.Yaml is successfull,**

But when opening main.dart file it shows the error

Problem(1)

```
 The Target URI doesn't Exist:
'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Either

```
flutter packages get
```

needs to be run or failed when you run it

or you just need to restart your IDE. I saw it mentioned a few times recently that this was necessary to fix the problem.

Comment: Re starting the whole Project fixed this issue thaks!

Answer (score 3):

**1-** Go to the link: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database#-installing-tab-

**2-** Add dependencies in pubspec.yaml file.e.g:-

dependencies:

flutter:

```
sdk: flutter
```

firebase_database: ^3.1.3

**3-** Press ctrl+s after two seconds it will give a message click on Get Dependencies, and wait for some time its will run pub get in your project.

**4-** Problem will be solved.